# Amending my code: currently using toggle() and toggleClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## Some of my code does not communicate what it needs to.

On these IDs

- #html-button
- #css-button
- #js-button
- #result-button

I added a class called **.selected**. The way I wrote the code, works great as is. But, when I remove selected from any of those IDs, I would then have to add new CSS and add "display: none" to any of the corresponding viewport containers:

- #html-container
- #css-container
- #js-container
- #result-container.

I do realize that I can create some if statements but I also would like to learn some new methods / functions that can help me. One thing I like is clear readable code that is efficient. So having a bunch of un-needed checks and loops is not my goal.

Based off the method I chose to use *toggle()* and *toggleClass()* does not communicate well together (in my code) **when trying to manually remove .selected class without manually adding a display: none to my ID container divs.**

The reason I would want to manually remove the *.selected* class is because I might want to change the default ID containers that are open when the app loads.

---

Would someone be willing to shed some new light on some different ideas on how to approach this?

---

[My Editable code on CSSDeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/full/emuwtava) < basically like jsfiddle or jsbin.

### Javascript

```
    $('.code-container').css('height', $(window).innerHeight() - 39 + "px");
$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.code-container').css('height', $(window).innerHeight() - 39 + "px");
});


$("[id$=button]").click(function () {

    $(this).toggleClass('selected');

    // creates the name of a viewport ID. "view-" + html of button
    var viewID = "#" + $(this).html() + "-container";
    $(viewID).toggle();

    var viewSize = $(window).innerWidth()/$('.selected').length;
    $(".code-container").css("width", viewSize);
}
);

$('#run').click( function() {
    var html = $('#htmlCode').val();
    var css = $('#cssCode').val();
    var js = $('#jsCode').val();
    $('#iframe').contents().find("html").html("<style>" + css + "</style>" + html);
});
```

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Code Player</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <div id="header">
            <p id="logo">CodePlayer</p>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li id="html-button"    class="toggle selected no-highlight">html</li>
                    <li id="css-button"     class="toggle selected no-highlight">css</li>
                    <li id="js-button"      class="toggle selected no-highlight">js</li>
                    <li id="result-button"  class="toggle selected no-highlight">result</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="run" class="no-select">Run</div>
        </div>

        <div id="html-container" class="code-container">
            <div class="code-label">HTML</div>
            <textarea id="htmlCode"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="css-container" class="code-container">
            <div class="code-label">CSS</div>
            <textarea id="cssCode"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="js-container" class="code-container">
            <div class="code-label">JS</div>
            <textarea id="jsCode"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="result-container" class="code-container">
            <div class="code-label">Result</div>
            <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
        </div>



    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

### CSS

```
/* Global Settings */
* { padding: 0; margin: 0;}
body {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.no-highlight {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

/* Header Logo Toggles and Buttons */
#header {
    width: 100%; height: 28px;
    background-color: #222;
    padding: 4px;
}
#header #logo {
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px; top: 4px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    line-height: 28px

}
#header nav {   
    width: 226px; height: 28px;
    margin: auto;
}

/* Look and Feel of buttons */
#header li, #run {
    width: 50px; height: 26px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #aaa;
    border: 1px solid #00a2ff;
    border-radius: 6px;
    font-size: .8em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    line-height: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}
/* ads margin ONLY between li elements */
#header li+li {
    margin-left: 6px;
}
/* Run button positioning */
#run {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px; top: 4px;
}
/* special class to differentiate toggled buttons */
#header .selected, #header #run {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

/* end of Button styling */






/* code-container is the html, css, js and result viewports */
.code-container {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
/* textarea for user input of code */
.code-container textarea {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    padding: 18px 3px 3px 3px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    border-right: 1px solid #222;
    font-family: monospace;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
/* viewport name */
.code-label {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px; right: 5px;
}
/* viewport for the code output result */
iframe {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    border: none;
}
```

Comment: every pane in your cssdeck link is empty

Comment: LOL. Click edit code on top right corner. CSS deck is not my project! I am making a code player - just for a fun project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good. Nevertheless there are certain points which can be improved in your realization.

Here are my proposals:

1. Don't rely on the innerHtml of your button's for identifying them. I introduced a new `data-pane` attribute. You could use the `id` as well (if you strip the `"-button"` substring)
2. Use named functions and structure your code
3. Hide all `.container` elements by default in your CSS and show all panes with `"selected"` buttons when bootstrapping your application

## [Here is a DEMO](http://cssdeck.com/labs/gr7lobub)

### The changes

**HTML**

I removed the `selected` class of the first item for demonstration purposes. Also I added the `data-pane` attribute:

```
<li id="html-button"    class="toggle no-highlight" data-pane="html">html</li>
<li id="css-button"     class="toggle selected no-highlight" data-pane="css">css</li>
<li id="js-button"      class="toggle selected no-highlight" data-pane="js">js</li>
<li id="result-button"  class="toggle selected no-highlight" data-pane="result">result</li>
```

**CSS**

I added `display: none;`

```
.code-container {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
```

**JS**

I rewrote major parts of it, but here are only the new parts.

This shows all panes that are selected when the app starts:

```
  $('.selected').each(function() {
    var pane = $(this).data('pane');
    showPane(pane);
  });
```

This gives you the information you need to decide what to toggle:

```
  var pane = $(this).data('pane');
  var isSelected = $(this).hasClass('selected');

  if(isSelected) {  
    hidePane(pane);
  } else {
    showPane(pane);
  }
```

These are the new show and hide functions. They bundle all needed actions to update the view:

```
function showPane(pane) {
  $('#' + pane + '-button').addClass('selected');
  $('#' + pane + '-container').show();
  updateContainers();
}

function hidePane(pane) {
  $('#' + pane + '-button').removeClass('selected');
  $('#' + pane + '-container').hide();
  updateContainers();
}

function updateContainers() {
  var viewSize = $(window).innerWidth() / $('.selected').length;
  $(".code-container").css("width", viewSize);
}
```

As you can see, no manual `display: none;` is needed.

Comment: This is a really awesome answer Alp. each() is really nice. Thank you. I am having a hard time understanding var pane = $('.selected').data('pane'); I get an error associated with this.data() not being a function. also what is up with data-pane="html" ?? I have never seen this and do not see on your code where that is used. data('pane') is the closest, but I do not understand. Care to evaluate?

Comment: Im sorry. I just do not get   $('.selected').each(function() {
    var pane = $(this).data('pane');
    showPane(pane);
  });
what exactly is data('pane') storing to var pane?

Comment: Well, I did not realize that data() can be used with new html5 attribute, "data-". This is actually really awesome. I understand the code now and have learned SO much!!! http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/ as well as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

Comment: Glad i could help! If you have any further questions, don't hesitate to ask. Also, it would be nice if you accept my answer as solution.